# Join against date range, aggregate by SUM

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I need to gather the SUM of sales made on a certain category item, grouped by day for a selected date range (could be from a week out to 12weeks) and return 0 instead of NULL for days where no transactions have occurred.

My original idea was to use a pre-populated table called "calendar" (shown below) which has about 10yrs of dates which I could LEFT JOIN my "products" table against to get days when no sales occurred as a 0 SUM.

Result was too large to deal with, so I'm trying to first copy the selected range of dates to an empty table called "datetable" which shares the same column names as "calendar". So I have 3 tables:

"**calendar**" table. It has 10 years worth of dates with following column names:

```
IsoDate       DayNameOfWeek

2012-01-01       Sun
2012-01-02       Mon
2012-01-03       Tue
2012-01-04       Wed
2012-01-05       Thu
2012-01-06       Fri
2012-01-07       Sat
2012-01-08       Sun
2012-01-09       Mon
2012-01-10       Tue
etc for 10yrs
```

"**datetable**" table (this is created empty with two columns to prefill from "calendar" table so the date range data for the LEFT JOIN is more compact):

```
IsoDate        DayNameOfWeek
```

"**products**" table. It is where I'm storing sales for each ProductCat:

```
ExpDate     ProductCat  Amount

2012-01-03    28          232
2012-01-04    29          100
2012-01-04    29          1002
2012-01-06    12          12
2012-01-06    29          9
2012-01-07    10          100
2012-01-07    29          122
2012-01-07    29          17
```

The output I'm looking for based on a single "ProductCat" number, in this case 29:

```
IsoDate     DayNameOfWeek   AmountSummed

2012-01-01     Sun      0
2012-01-02     Mon      0
2012-01-03     Tue      0
2012-01-04     Wed      1102
2012-01-05     Thu      0
2012-01-06     Fri      9
2012-01-07     Sat      139
2012-01-08     Sun      0
2012-01-09     Mon      0
2012-01-10     Tue      0
```

My code is below. The initial insert works fine but I'm not sure of the syntax that will make the second part with the JOIN and the SUM work:

```
INSERT INTO datetable (IsoDate, DayNameOfWeek)
SELECT IsoDate, DayNameOfWeek
FROM calendar
WHERE IsoDate 
BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-10'

SELECT ExpDate, SUM(IFNULL(Amount, 0))
AS AmountSummed
FROM products
WHERE ProductCat = 29
AND ExpDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-10'
LEFT JOIN products 
ON datetable.IsoDate=products.ExpDate
    GROUP BY datetable.IsoDate
```

**EDIT**

This is the code that works now:

```
SELECT C.IsoDate,IFNULL(SUM(P.Amount),0) AS AmountSummed
FROM calendar C LEFT OUTER JOIN products P ON C.IsoDate=P.ExpDate
AND P.ProductCat = 29
WHERE C.IsoDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-10'
GROUP BY C.IsoDate, C.DayNameOfWeek
ORDER BY C.IsoDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty much got what you need.  However, you don't need the **datetable**.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT C.IsoDate, C.DayNameOfWeek, IFNULL(SUM(P.Amount),0) AS AmountSummed
FROM calendar C LEFT JOIN products P ON C.IsoDate=P.ExpDate
WHERE C.IsoDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-10'
  AND P.ProductCat = 29
GROUP BY C.IsoDate, C.DayNameOfWeek
ORDER BY C.IsoDate
```

If you really want to use your `datetable`, just substitute it in for `calendar` and remove the `C.IsoDate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-10'` (assuming that the `datetable` was empty before you started) because `datetime` already has all the date you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Holger, This works well because it lets me remove the need for the datetable...But  I don't seem to be able to return a 0 sum for those days in the 10 days range which have no entries in the "products" table.. so days: 01, 02,05,08,09,10.  Is there a tweak I can do to get that?   Thanks M

Comment: @MarcoPolo, I switched the order of IFNULL and SUM. That should fix it. Alternately, instead of IFNULL and SUM, you can just use TOTAL(), but it returns a floating number (0.0).

Comment: Hi Holger, I modified your code slightly because I still couldn't get it to work, it was still chopping out days with no entries. So I moved the "P.ProductCat = 29" up into the JOIN bit and left the date range in the WHERE and it seems to work. :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. M